# What is sleep pressure?

Tags: sleep, terminology, sleep-cycles

What is sleep pressure?

I was reading [an article on melatonin](https://www.talkaboutsleep.com/how-to-use-melatonin-correctly/), and one of the commenters said something about 'sleep pressure'. I did a web search to see what it was, but web searches don't often seem to allow exact phrase matches anymore (so, I got results about other sleep topics and blood pressure instead).

The commenter said, among other things, "The other, the S process is influenced by sleep pressure."

The [Wikipedia article on sleep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep) mentions homeostatic sleep pressure (but it doesn't define it; nor does it mention another kind of sleep pressure).

Comment: A web search on `homeostatic sleep pressure` yields many results.